# css styling issue when coming from javascript

Tags: html, css

I have an application where some text is coming after message getting parsed like this :

```
<div class='message'>
    <p ng-bind-html="main.parseMsg(msg)"></p>
</div>
```

I have written some css for the `.message p {}`.

My `parseMsg` sometimes returns something like this

```
<div class='something'><p>...</p>
```

I want the `something` class to not inherit css properties from `.message p{}` at all.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple CSS ways to fix your hierarchy (like adding a class to your binding `p`, etc.) but there's another issue: *You cannot have a p inside of a p*.

This nested `p` markup:

```
<div>
 <p>1<p>2</p></p>
</div>
```

Actually turns into three `p`'s as direct children of the `div` as the browser renders it to make it valid markup:

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

So, to better answer your question and fix your "paragraph-problem" you will want to change your `p` that is bound to be an element that is allowed to contain multiple `p`'s. Here, we'll use a `div`:

```
// Template:
<div class="message">
  <div ng-bind-html="main.parseMsg(msg)"></div>
</div>

// CSS:
.message > div { /* Your child container element */ }.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your css

```
.message > p {
    //styles
}
```